# I need get public method from other component in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need to call headerExpand property from app.component but when I try to make this, show me this in the console:

> metadata_resolver.js:559Uncaught Error: Invalid providers for "Page1" - only instances of Provider and Type are allowed, got: [?undefined?]

page1.ts

```
<pre>
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MyApp } from '../../app/app.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-page1',
  templateUrl: 'page1.html',

})
export class Page1 {

  constructor(public miApp: MyApp) {
    console.log(miApp.headerExpand);

  }

</pre>
```

app.component.ts

```
<pre>
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

  rootPage: any = Page1;
  public headerExpand: boolean;
  public pages: Array<{title: string, component: any}>;

  constructor(public platform: Platform) {
    this.initializeApp();
    this.headerExpand = true;


  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    });
  }

  openPage(page) {
    // Reset the content nav to have just this page
    // we wouldn't want the back button to show in this scenario
    this.nav.setRoot(page.component);
  }



  expandHeader(){
    this.headerExpand = false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to **inject** parent component to children component. You should e.g. use **Output()** in this scenario (children to parent). Take a look here:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html